# Find The Top Level Parent And Multiply Quantities

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables which track part numbers as well as the hierarchy of assemblies.

Table: Config

```
ConfigNum  AssemblyNum  Qty
 1            A        1
 1            B        2
 1            C        2
 2            A        1
 2            C        1
```

Table: SubAssembly

```
 SubAssembly  PartNum  Qty
 A          AA     2
 A          BB     4
 A          CC     2
 A          DD     4
 B          EE     4
 B          FF     8
 AA         AAA    2
```

I would like to create a flat version of these tables which shows the `ConfigNum` (Top level parent) with all associated assembly and part numbers, for each `ConfigNum` in the Config table. The column `Config.AssemblyNum` is equivalent to `SubAssembly.SubAssembly`.

Comment: I am guessing that "server" means "sql-server".  You should tag the question with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem I think you must use a recursive query. In fact I think SubAssembly table should have some ProductID field other than SubAssembly to easily identify the main product that contains assemblies.

You can find a similar example in SLQ Server documentation.

Can check it here: http://rextester.com/FQYI80157

Change the Qty in Config table to change the final result.

```
create table #t1 (cfg int, part varchar(10), qty int);
create table #t2 (part varchar(10), sasm varchar(10), qty int);
insert into #t1 values (1,'A',2);
insert into #t2 values ('AA','AAA',2),('A','AA',2),('A','BB',4),('A','CC',2),('A','DD',4);

WITH cte(sasm, part, qty) 
AS (
    SELECT sasm, part, qty 
    FROM #t2 WHERE part = 'A'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT p.sasm, p.part, p.qty * pr.qty
    FROM cte pr, #t2 p
    WHERE p.part = pr.sasm
  )
SELECT #t1.cfg, cte.part, cte.sasm, SUM(cte.qty * COALESCE(#t1.qty,1)) as total_quantity
FROM cte
left join #t1 on cte.part = #t1.part
GROUP BY #t1.cfg, cte.part, cte.sasm;
```

This is the result:

```
+---+------+------+------+----------------+
|   | cfg  | part | sasm | total_quantity |
+---+------+------+------+----------------+
| 1 | NULL | AA   | AAA  |              4 |
| 2 | 1    | A    | AA   |              4 |
| 3 | 1    | A    | BB   |              8 |
| 4 | 1    | A    | CC   |              4 |
| 5 | 1    | A    | DD   |              8 |
+---+------+------+------+----------------+
```